# When I tried to execute load.sql in phpMyAdmin, it gave me an error

Tags: php, mysql, hosting

I'm trying to use 000webhost.com to host my website. My website is simply an imdb-clone that uses PHP and MYSQL. When I tried to import a file to my database, it gave me the error shown below. I'm confused because I do have the file "movie.del" in the following path. I have "movie.del" inside the sql folder.

Please let me know what you guys think. This problem has been bothering for a few days now and I haven't found any helpful solution online. Thanks!!!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6cQK.png)

Comment: You have the file but the website doesn't.

Comment: The file is not found. That should be a pretty straight forward error to trouble shoot.

Comment: Ok, but idk how to find the correct path... Do you guys how I can find the right path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the file but the website doesn't. `~/Desktop/tmp/sql/movie.del` is a local machine path. Replace that path with a path used by your webserver.

Comment: How do I find out the path that is used by my webserver? I don't think I know what the path used by my webserver is.. Could you help me out? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know. But, you can find out in many ways. If you have SSH access, go to the path and run a `pwd` command. If not, you can write a PHP script that output the path for you, than you can use it.